# NOT IN Subquery slow and runs out of memory (Clickhouse)

Tags: clickhouse

I have a single table holding DNA variants for different people. I want to show the variants that are unique to a person:

Table DNA (engine ordered by variant):

```
   person | variant
   p1     | v1 
   p1     | v2 
   p1     | v3 
   p2     | v2 
   p2     | v3 
   p3     | v2 
   p3     | v3
   p4     | v2 
   p4     | v3
```

So a simple query:

```
   select variant from DNA where person = 'p1' and variant 
     not in (select variant from DNA where person in ('p2', 'p3'))
```

will return all variants unique to p1 vs. p2 and p3 (p4 not considered for this query). However - it is slow and runs out of memory.

Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: You should also show us how your table is created

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the reason it is running out of memory is that the `select variant from DNA where person in ('p2', 'p3')` sub-query will result in `v2, v3, v2, v3`. This, especially when brought to scale, seems exceedingly inefficient because of the repetition. Potentially, adding `distinct` to the query may help, but in general this seems like an inefficient method of achieving your results if you have a lot of people (you'd have to manually type a lot of people in `where person in (.........)`.

An alternative to this is to do a self join and basically limit the results to those where the only match is itself. Something like:

```
SELECT person, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table
    ALL LEFT JOIN table
    USING variant
)
GROUP BY person
HAVING COUNT(*) == 1;
```